# Removing "\n" between the line in multiline string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, replace, python-re

I want to remove "\n" from the intext in python. I tried many ways but all didn't work. The text suppose to be something like this:

```
string='''# Initializing Function named main()
def main () :
    str1 = None
    str2 = None
    age=16
    str1=str(input())
    str2=str(input())
    print("Entered Name: {}\n".format(str1))
    print("Entered Website:{}".format(str2))
# Calling the main Function
main()'''
```

In line **"print("Entered Name: {}\n".format(str1))"** there is \n which I need to remove without removing other \n from muliline string. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "without removing the other \n from multiline string"?Please be more clear

Comment: @SamyakJain I need to remove "\n" in the line  "print("Entered Name: {}\n".format(str1))"   without removing other \n.As "string" is a multiline string so it contains \n after each line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the multiline string as a raw string so the `\n` isn't escaped, then replace it (using another raw string so it is not escaped yet again):

```py
# r before the ''' makes it a raw string
string=r'''# Initializing Function named main()
def main () :
    str1 = None
    str2 = None
    age=16
    str1=str(input())
    str2=str(input())
    print("Entered Name: {}\n".format(str1))
    print("Entered Website:{}".format(str2))
# Calling the main Function
main()'''
string = string.replace(r'\n', '')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. can you tell me how to convert multiline string to raw string without using 'r' in front?

Comment: @YashMakan - There is no conversion; the 'r' in front is more of a parsing directive, telling the parser how to convert the text into code, and the resulting string has no difference to a non-raw string. `r'abc'` is exactly the same as `'abc'`, to the extent that in many cases `r'abc' is 'abc'` may evaluate to `True`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `\n` is interpreted by the `'''` string, but you want it to be left in place and processed by the inner `"` string.

The simplest solution is to use an r-string for the outer one; note the `r'''` on the first line:

```
string=r'''# Initializing Function named main()
def main () :
    str1 = None
    str2 = None
    age=16
    str1=str(input())
    str2=str(input())
    print("Entered Name: {}\n".format(str1))
    print("Entered Website:{}".format(str2))
# Calling the main Function
main()'''
```

With that change, the inner `\n` should work correctly and you'll probably no longer need to remove it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. can you tell me how to convert multiline string to raw string without using 'r' in front?

Comment: @Programming_Hub: You can't. That `r` is what makes it a raw string; without the `r`, it's not raw by definition. You could double-escape (or more precisely, escape the escape on) the `n` to make it `\\n` and get the same effect with a non-raw string.

Comment: if I replace \n with \\n then the structure of the complete string change by replacing all the other \n.

Comment: @YashMakan: No, it doesn't. That single `\\n` would be a literal backslash followed by the letter `n`, and all the other literal newlines would remain plain newlines. You'd need to replace with a raw string or similarly escaped search string `.replace('\\n', ...)` or `.replace(r'\n', ...)` to match, that's all.

Comment: Once you have the literal `\n` in the string, you probably don't want to replace anyway - you'll be running it through some form of Python which will deal with the `\n` appropriately.

Comment: The underlying problem here is that the text is going through multiple levels of handling, and we're conflating the levels. We need to carefully distinguish which parts get interpreted in the outer python and which in the inner python.

Answer (score -1):

```
i = string.find('{}\\n') #is the position of the '{}\n'
string = string[:i+2] + string[i+5 :] #should do the trick
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it'll only work for this string and not any other string.

Comment: I would suggest to try and apply my approach: finding the position of the \n and deleting it "by hand" because you may need to use multilinear comment with format and you are not going to be able to use the r''' ''' method. I would only use that if there were many '\n' to get rid of.