# Multiline String to raw string Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, replace, python-re

I  have a multiline string. I need to convert that string to raw string without using r' ' while declaring the variable. My main motive is to convert \n present in line **"print("Entered Name: {}\n".format(str1))"** and not to convert other \n in the multiline string.

```
string='''# Initializing Function named main()
def main () :
    str1 = None
    str2 = None
    age=16
    str1=str(input())
    str2=str(input())
    print("Entered Name: {}\n".format(str1))
    print("Entered Website:{}".format(str2))
# Calling the main Function
main()'''
```

> Note: I am not able to use string=r' ' ' # Initializing Function named
> main()...

**Code Thant I tried but didn't work :**

```
string='''# Initializing Function named main()
def main () :
    str1 = None
    str2 = None
    age=16
    str1=str(input())
    str2=str(input())
    print("Entered Name: {}\n".format(str1))
    print("Entered Website:{}".format(str2))
# Calling the main Function
main()'''
string=r"{}".format(string)
string = string.replace(r'\n', '')
print(string)
```

Thanks!

Comment: "I need to convert that string to raw string without using r' ' while declaring the variable" - it sounds like you've misunderstood what a "raw string" is. A raw string literal is a way of writing strings, which disables escape sequence processing. You cannot undo escape sequence processing that has already happened, and you cannot convert an existing string to a raw string.

Comment: Why do you think you cannot use the `r` prefix?

Comment: The `r` is the way to go or a doubled backslash. Otherwise the `\n` can't be differentiated from a linebreak.

Comment: Actually, I am getting the string variable by a function(def) and that is why I am not able to add r prefix on my own

Comment: There is nothing in that string that would be changed by `r` anyway...

Comment: @JohnGordon: There's a `\n`.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Ahh, there is one.  My bad.

Comment: @YashMakan: What do you mean by "getting the string variable by a function(def)"? If the string ultimately comes from a string literal somewhere (perhaps in the function's source code), then put an `r` there. If it ultimately comes from user input, or reading a file, or some source other than a string literal, then there is no escape sequence processing to undo, and none of this is necessary.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I was finding a better way to pass the string in function without using r ' '. Thanks, everyone for the support. Stackoverflow is gr8...

Comment: "Convert to raw string" is a nonsense request.  Raw strings are just a convenient way of writing string literals without having to double-backslash everything.  The result string ends up having exactly the same value.

Answer (score 0):

As [I already said the last time you asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65101379/removing-n-between-the-line-in-multiline-string-in-python#comment115093960_65101405) **You cannot make a raw string without the `r` prefix**. That is, by definition, what makes it a raw string. You can use a normal, non-raw string, and just escape the escape:

```
string='''# Initializing Function named main()
    ...
    print("Entered Name: {}\\n".format(str1))
    ...
main()'''
```

Note extra backslash, which makes the string use an actual backslash followed by an `n` in the string there, while the literal newlines remain newlines, allowing you to replace one without affecting the other.

Comment: @YashMakan: By clicking before the `\n` in your text editor and hitting the backslash key.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica kindly understand that the string given in the query is merely an example. I am getting the string by a function so there can be any string with \n anywhere in the code.

Comment: @YashMakan: "Getting the string by a function" is extremely ambiguous. If the string ultimately comes from a string literal somewhere, put the `r` there. If it doesn't come from a string literal, then there is almost certainly no escape sequence processing to undo anyway.

Comment: Elaborating on @user2357112supportsMonica, if you have a string that *already* mixes formatting newlines with "code" newlines, your problem is that they're both newlines, indistinguishable in any way. You can't retroactively tell Python that some of them are "real" newlines and some aren't without running them through some custom parser (well beyond the scope of StackOverflow) that can tell, from context, which one each is meant to be (in this case, you'd essentially need to reinvent the Python parser from scratch, and even then, it'd be heuristic when the code itself had multiline strings).